# Angular Workspace with specific dependencies per project

Tags: angular

I understand a workspace gathers together multiple angular project/libraries to be able to share config files.

But then there is only a single `node_modules` folder. This means when a package is installed, it is added to all projects and libraries. Is this intended ?

Or does this mean the package is available in the  `node_modules` but it will only be used by a project/library if it is referenced in the imports  ?

Comment: It's only available and will be used if referenced.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming that.